# Xamarin Android C# Timer error

Tags: c#, android, timer, xamarin

My android app uses a timer in a certain place.
I get an exception when the time exceeds an hour (3600000), it says the period is too large.

```
myTime = "3600000";

TempTimer = new System.Threading.Timer ((o) => {
    ContentCheck(); // function call/ Void call <----------
}, null, 0, Int64.Parse(myTime)  );
```

I've tried `int.parse()` already, so tried `int64` (Hence it being in code..)

Is there a timer that can do an hour AND longer? Or perhaps and alternative method to get the same results as a timer?

Comment: Why are you storing the interval as a string?

Comment: Long story involving JSON server transactions.. so it's not stored just passed along. But that shouldn't matter thou..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 3600000; 
        timer.AutoReset = false; 
        timer.Start ();
        timer.Elapsed+= Timer_Elapsed;


    void Timer_Elapsed (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Timer has gone off");
    }
```

Here the interval property of timer instance is of type Double. So that can store really large values. So this should work for you.

Comment: Timer Interval as Double ? .. Perfect!! Thank you !